# PHP virtual() doesn't send data to client

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to do some processing then pass along variables to an `shtml` file that is included with `virtual()`. Yes, I have to use this file and cannot simply do all the processing in php.

In Chrome if I use `echo " ";` before I call `virtual()`, it displays the page properly, but displays a blank page if I don't use `echo`.

In other browsers it displays no content.

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried playing with the headers set by php but I've had no luck so far.

Comment: Is there any chance we can observe this behavior live?

Comment: See the bottom comment in the documentation: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php. It describes an issue when `virtual` produces the first output, and the workaround is to use `echo " ";`.

Comment: Well, if that's the workaround, the problem may lay in output buffering, so a check on that and a possible `ob_flush()`/`flush()` might do some good...